# How to interlace string with one character?

Tags: c++

I need to write a function that replaces for example `"string"` with `"s't'r'i'n'g"`.

I added string to array and... what's next?

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string x;
    cout << "Type a string: ";
        cin >> x;
    char array[x.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(array); i++) {
        array[i] = x[i];
        cout << array[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Please add more details and a [mcve]. And a *clear/specific/unambiguous* question.

Comment: This is usually referred to as "joining". And what have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: `char array[x.length()];` note that standard `c++` does not permit this. arrays must have a compile time constant size.

Comment: You rather want another `std::string` for the result than a raw array. The whole array thing is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

> I added string to array

That's your first mistake. You don't use arrays for strings in C++ but `std::string`.

> and... what's next?

Dunnno? Write code?

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void interlace(std::string &str, char ch)
{
    for (std::size_t pos{ 1 }; pos < str.length(); pos += 2)
        str.insert(pos, 1, ch);
}

int main()
{
    std::string foo{ "string" };
    interlace(foo, '\'');
    std::cout << foo << '\n';
}
```

#### Output:

```
s't'r'i'n'g
```

#### Possible Optimization:

As suggested by [Remy Lebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau), `interlace()` could make sure it's parameter `str` has enough memory reserved before entering the `for`-loop to avoid reallocations within the loop:

```cpp
void interlace(std::string &str, char ch)
{
    auto length{ str.length() };

    if (length < 2)  // nothing to do
        return;

    str.reserve(2 * length - 1);  // We insert a character after every character of str
                                  // but the last one. eg. length == 3 -> 2 * 3 - 1

    for (std::size_t pos{ 1 }; pos < str.length(); pos += 2)
        str.insert(pos, 1, ch);
}
```

#### Btw:

- Please mind: `<string>`, not `<string.h>`. If you *really* want the string functions from C (`std::strlen()`, `std::strcpy()`, ...), they're in `<cstring>` in C++.
- Better drop the habit of `using namespace std;` because it inserts all identifiers from `std` into the global namespace which can easily lead to conflicting identifiers. That may be no problem for very small programs, but ...
- That:

  > ```
  > char array[x.length()];
  > ```

  is not legal C++. Array sizes must be compile-time constants. What you're using here is a `gcc` language extension. You shouldn't. Those things are called VLAs (Variable Length Arrays) which is a feature of C. When you need something that behaves like an array but has dynamic size use a `std::vector<>`.